# Вывод таблицы БД через сервлет

Tags: java, servlet

Имеется класс сервлета(указанный в web.xml), задача которого - вывести таблицу из БД.

```
public class ResumeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private SqlStorage sqlStorage;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        sqlStorage = new SqlStorage(Config.get().getDbUrl(),
                Config.get().getDbUser(),
                Config.get().getDbPassword());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        printResume(response);
    }

    private void printResume(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        List<Resume> list = sqlStorage.getSortedStorage();
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.println("<table>\n" +
                "<tbody>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<th>UUID</th>\n" +
                "<th>Full Name</th>\n" +
                "</tr>");

        for (Resume r : list) {
            writer.println("<tr>");
            writer.println("<td>" + r.getUuid() + "</td>");
            writer.println("<td>" + r.getFullName() + "</td>");
            writer.println("</tr>");
        }

        writer.println("</tbody\n" +
                "</table>");
    }
}
```

Далее прилагаю сами настройки index.html, web.xml и стектрейс из Tomcat. Проблема - при вызове сервлета вылетают ошибки; но т.к. я в сервлетах новичок - я вообще не пойму, куда здесь нужно копать

```
//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Практика Java. Разработка Web приложения.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Приложение вебинара <a href="https://javaops.ru/view/basejava" target="_blank"> "Практика Java. Разработка Web
    приложения"</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resumeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.javawebinar.basejava.web.ResumeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resumeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resume</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Ну и собственно сами ошибки:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [resumeServlet] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [resumeServlet] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.javawebinar.basejava.Config
    ru.javawebinar.basejava.web.ResumeServlet.init(ResumeServlet.java:20)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

В чем я ошибаюсь и что я упустил?

**Upd. - добавил код самого конфига. JUnit без проблем подключается через него к БД и тесты проходят; жалуется именно сервлет**

```
public class Config {
    private static final File PROPS = new File("config/resumes.properties");
    private static final Config INSTANCE = new Config();

    private Properties props = new Properties();
    private File storageDir;
    private String dbUrl;
    private String dbUser;
    private String dbPassword;

    public static Config get() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Config() {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(PROPS)) {
            props.load(is);
            storageDir = new File(props.getProperty("storage.dir"));
            dbUrl = props.getProperty("db.url");
            dbUser = props.getProperty("db.user");
            dbPassword = props.getProperty("db.password");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid config file " + PROPS.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    public File getStorageDir() {
        return storageDir;
    }

    public String getDbUrl() {
        return dbUrl;
    }

    public String getDbUser() {
        return dbUser;
    }

    public String getDbPassword() {
        return dbPassword;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Servlet.init() for servlet [resumeServlet] ..." - значит ошибка в методе "init" вашего сервлета. А конкретно  - класс "ru.javawebinar.basejava.Config" не найден в класс пафе.

Answer (score 0):

Класс `Config` не инициализирован. Скорее всего надо просто инициализровать некоторые поля в [статическом блоке](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/bloki-inicializacii-v-java-chast-1) `static {/*код*/}`, не могу сказать точно т.к. вы не показали этот класс. 

И совет, лучше делать не через web.xml, а через аннотации, но с этим можно разобраться и позже

Comment: Я добавил код этого класса. Тестовый JUnit класс без проблем подключается к БД через этот конфиг и все тесты проходят...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась принудительной загрузкой класса через Class.forName() и прописью полного пути к файлу сервлета